# Getting "ImportError: cannot import name 'ALREADY_HANDLED' from 'eventlet.wsgi'" error on azure

Tags: azure, eventlet

I have been trying to deploy a flask app that uses flask_socketio , and i imported eventlet=0.33.3 , gunicorn=20.1.0, Flask-SocketIO==5.3.4 and python 3.11.3. the app worked well locally, but when deployed to azure, it failed to startup. These are the contents of of the app.py file :

```
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()
import os
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect, url_for, jsonify, session
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from src.main_app import process_pdf_and_query as main
from src.main_app import chat_with_model
from src.main_app import get_pinecone_namespaces
from src.main_app import generate_answer
import logging
import time
from datetime import datetime

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")

app.logger.info("App started")

logger = logging.getLogger("govGPT_usage")
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

file_handler = logging.FileHandler("govGPT_usage.log")
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.addHandler(file_handler)

UPLOAD_FOLDER = "files"
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {"pdf"}


app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)
app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"] = UPLOAD_FOLDER


def create_directory_if_not_exists(directory):
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)


def allowed_file(filename):
    return "." in filename and filename.rsplit(".", 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        query = request.form["query"]
        search_scope = request.form["search_scope"]
        namespace = (
            request.form["namespace"]
            if not request.form.get("namespace-disabled", "false") == "true"
            else None
        )

        print(f"Query: {query}")
        print(f"Search scope: {search_scope}")
        print(f"Selected namespace: {namespace}")

        if "pdf" in request.files and request.files["pdf"].filename != "":
            file = request.files["pdf"]
            if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
                filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
                file.save(os.path.join(app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"], filename))
                pdf_path = os.path.join(app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"], filename)
            else:
                pdf_path = None
        else:
            pdf_path = None

        department = request.form.get("department")
        type_of_document = request.form.get("type_of_document")
        year = request.form.get("year")

        search_results = main(
            query, search_scope, pdf_path, namespace, department, type_of_document, year
        )


        if pdf_path:
            os.remove(pdf_path)  # Delete the PDF file after processing

        session["query"] = query
        session["search_results"] = search_results
        session["department"] = department
        session["type_of_document"] = type_of_document
        session["year"] = year
        session["namespace"] = namespace
        session["search_scope"] = search_scope
        session["pdf_path"] = pdf_path
        return redirect(url_for("result"))
    namespaces = get_pinecone_namespaces()
    return render_template("index.html", namespaces=namespaces)


@app.route("/result")
def result():
    query = session.get("query", "")
    search_results = session.get("search_results", "")
    return render_template("results.html", query=query, search_results=search_results)


@socketio.on("get_answer", namespace="/results")
def get_answer():
    query = session.get("query", "")
    search_results = session.get("search_results", "")
    answer = generate_answer(query, search_results)
    search_scope = session.get("search_scope", "")
    namespace = session.get("namespace", "")
    pdf_path = session.get("pdf_path", "")
    department = session.get("department", "")
    type_of_document = session.get("type_of_document", "")
    year = session.get("year", "")

    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    log_message = f"Timestamp: {timestamp}, Query: {query}, Search scope: {search_scope}, Namespace: {namespace}, PDF Path: {pdf_path}, Department: {department}, Type of Document: {type_of_document}, Year: {year}, Answer: {answer}, Search Results: {search_results}"
    logger.info(log_message)
    print(f"Generated answer: {answer}")
    emit("answer_ready", {"answer": answer})


@app.route("/chat", methods=["POST"])
def chat():
    if request.method == "POST":
        query = request.form["query"]
        context = request.form["context"]
        answer = chat_with_model(context, query)
        return jsonify(answer=answer)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app)
```

The app ran well on the local server. But when i deployed it to azure, it failed to startup , and these were the generated logs :

"

```
2023-05-12T11:54:30.548100173Z Starting periodic command scheduler: cron.
2023-05-12T11:54:30.549440088Z Launching oryx with: create-script -appPath /home/site/wwwroot -output /opt/startup/startup.sh -virtualEnvName antenv -defaultApp /opt/defaultsite -userStartupCommand 'gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 --worker-class eventlet app:app
2023-05-12T11:54:30.549457988Z '
2023-05-12T11:54:30.611769182Z Found build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'. Deserializing it...
2023-05-12T11:54:30.613659803Z Build Operation ID: 3966f61573566a2d
2023-05-12T11:54:30.618312555Z Oryx Version: 0.2.20230322.1, Commit: 6c04ec75685b441c9378c238b6491cf9812313db, ReleaseTagName: 20230322.1
2023-05-12T11:54:30.618356556Z Output is compressed. Extracting it...
2023-05-12T11:54:30.625011230Z Extracting '/home/site/wwwroot/output.tar.gz' to directory '/tmp/8db52deb9f024a6'...
2023-05-12T11:54:47.740036487Z App path is set to '/tmp/8db52deb9f024a6'
2023-05-12T11:54:48.049341944Z Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
2023-05-12T11:54:48.279114912Z Using packages from virtual environment antenv located at /tmp/8db52deb9f024a6/antenv.
2023-05-12T11:54:48.286554395Z Updated PYTHONPATH to '/opt/startup/app_logs:/tmp/8db52deb9f024a6/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages'
2023-05-12T11:54:53.888455873Z
2023-05-12T11:54:53.888520074Z Error: class uri 'eventlet' invalid or not found:
2023-05-12T11:54:53.888525874Z
2023-05-12T11:54:53.888529874Z [Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-05-12T11:54:53.888533674Z   File "/tmp/8db52deb9f024a6/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 99, in load_class
2023-05-12T11:54:53.888537674Z     mod = importlib.import_module('.'.join(components))
2023-05-12T11:54:53.888541275Z           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-05-12T11:54:53.888544875Z   File "/opt/python/3.11.2/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2023-05-12T11:54:53.888564775Z     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2023-05-12T11:54:53.888568775Z            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-05-12T11:54:53.888572575Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
2023-05-12T11:54:53.888576675Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
2023-05-12T11:54:53.888580275Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1149, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2023-05-12T11:54:53.888583875Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
2023-05-12T11:54:53.888587475Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
2023-05-12T11:54:53.888591075Z   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
2023-05-12T11:54:53.888594675Z   File "/tmp/8db52deb9f024a6/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/geventlet.py", line 20, in <module>
2023-05-12T11:54:53.888625776Z     from eventlet.wsgi import ALREADY_HANDLED as EVENTLET_ALREADY_HANDLED
2023-05-12T11:54:53.888629576Z ImportError: cannot import name 'ALREADY_HANDLED' from 'eventlet.wsgi' (/tmp/8db52deb9f024a6/antenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/eventlet/wsgi.py)
2023-05-12T11:54:53.888633376Z ]
2023-05-12T11:54:53.897018293Z
2023-05-12T11:54:55.664Z ERROR - Container pai_0_752680da for site pai has exited, failing site start
```

".

How should i handle this?